# Buddhist magazines

Tags: lay-buddhism, books

I'm looking for Buddhist magazines - relevant for lay practitioners - and would like to request a list of these if anyone can help

Examples of the sort of magazines i'm thinking of:

- [*Turning Wheel*](http://www.buddhistpeacefellowship.org/our-work/turning-wheel-media/)
- [*Mindfulness Bell*](https://www.mindfulnessbell.org/)

I'm grateful for help with this

Comment: specific organisations/ local groups may also have newslaetters/ magazines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some more links to Buddhist Magazines and Journals:

[*Tricycle Magazine | The Buddhist Review*](https://tricycle.org/). One has to subscribe in order to read the magazine.

> The Tricycle Foundation is dedicated to making Buddhist teachings and practices broadly available. Tricycle soon became the leading independent journal of Buddhism in the West, where it continues to be the most inclusive and widely read vehicle for the dissemination of Buddhist views and values.

[*Lion's Roar Magazine*](https://www.lionsroar.com/lions-roar-current-issue/).

> Lion's Roar is the website of the Buddhist magazines Lion's Roar (formerly Shambhala Sun) and Buddhadharma, with exclusive teachings, how-tos, news and commentary on Buddhism, dharma, meditation and mindfulness.

[*Buddha Weekly Online Magazine | Buddhist Practices, Mindfulness, Meditation*](https://buddhaweekly.com/pride-poison-can-pride-accomplishment-considered-good-thing-full-ambattha-sutta-pride-birth-fall/).

> Buddha Weekly is an online magazine covering most important areas of Buddhist living and practice, with special focus on Teachers, Meditation Practices, Buddhas, Dharma and Sangha. Buddha Weekly Magazine has published on different platforms since 2007. We often profile specific Buddhist practices, teachers and Gurus, and insights into problems we personally may have faced in our practices.

[*Buddhism Now Magazine*](https://buddhismnow.com/2020/10/07/dokusan-the-great-matter-by-kodo-sawaki/).

> Buddhism Now digital is an online magazine giving advice on how to practise Buddhism in everyday life. The articles are drawn from a variety of practitioners and traditions.

[*Mountain Record*](https://www.mountainrecord.org/print-journal/).

> Mountain Record is the oldest American Zen quarterly, a spiritual journal by the Zen Mountain Monastery with Rinzai & Soto Zen Buddhism teachings, poems & more.

[*Buddhist Door*](https://www.buddhistdoor.net/).

> Offers regular Buddhist news, glossary, art, and Bodhi Journal, featuring articles on Buddha's life, sutra commentaries, zen stories, and more.

[*Buddhist Society UK*](http://www.thebuddhistsociety.org.uk/).

> Publishes quarterly journal The Middle Way presenting articles by noted Buddhist teachers and scholars on various aspects of Buddhist theory, practice, history, etc.

[*Engaged Dharma*](https://engageddharma.com/).

> Articles and commentaries about Buddhist practice from a contemporary Western Zen perspective.

[*Daily Enlightenment*](http://thedailyenlightenment.com/).

> Free weekly Buddhist email newsletter.

[*Daily Zen*](https://www.dailyzen.com/).

> Produces On the Way journal - monthly selection of Zen, Buddhist, and Taoist classics.

[*Fearless Mountain*](https://www.abhayagiri.org/).

> Newsletter of Abhayagiri Monastery (USA), a Buddhist community in the tradition of Ajahn Chah.

[*Gentle Voice*](http://www.siddharthasintent.org/resources/publications/).

> Newsletter informing about the activities of Dzongsar Khyentse Rinpoche, as well as other Buddhist teachers and their teachings.

[*International Journal of Tantric Studies*](http://asiatica.org/ijts/).

> Scholarly journal dealing with both Buddhist and Hindu aspects of Tantra.

[*Journal Of Global Buddhism*](http://www.globalbuddhism.org/jgb/index.php/jgb/).

> Scholarly journal established to promote the study of Buddhism's globalization with a particular focus on non-Asian countries. Includes research articles, discussions, critical notes, bulletins, and reviews.

[*Pragmatic Buddhist*](http://www.pragmaticbuddhism.org/).

> Official newsletter site of the Center for Pragmatic Buddhism (CPB). Pragmatic Buddhism is a form of applied pragmatism, and can also be viewed as a naturalistic approach to spirituality.

[*Urthona*](https://urthona.com/).

> Selected articles from magazine exploring the arts and Western culture from a Buddhist perspective.